# Can light travel with a speed less than its speed at same time?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, faster-than-light

I know that the velocity of light with respect to anything is constant ($c$) . What, then,  is velocity of light with respect to light?

Answer (score 7):

When you say that an object $A$ has some velocity with respect to another object $B$, you are implying that there is a reference frame where $B$ is at rest, and $A$ moves with the aforementioned velocity in *that* reference frame. It makes no sense to talk about the movement of a photon with respect to another, because photons have no rest frame.

See: [Why can't we make measurements in a photon's rest frame when loop diagrams make measurements possible?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21959/why-cant-we-make-measurements-in-a-photons-rest-frame-when-loop-diagrams-make)
and [Does a photon in vacuum have a rest frame?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/16018/does-a-photon-in-vacuum-have-a-rest-frame)

Comment: Hritik Narayan: "_When you say that an object $A$ has some velocity with respect to another object $B$, you are implying that there is a reference frame where B is at rest_" -- I fully agree. This implies in particular that **additional participants** can be thought (or even actually be found) who were at rest wrt. $B$ and each other. "_and $A$ moves with the aforementioned velocity in that reference frame._" -- Or $A$ belonged to that frame, too. And, of course, $A$ might have variable instantaneous speeds. Or instantaneous speed $0$ wrt. $B$ and yet not be at rest wrt. $B$ ...

Answer (score 1):

When you say that an object $A$ has some velocity with respect to another object $B$, you are implying that there is a reference frame where $B$ is at rest. This means that additional participants ($J$, $K$, ... $P$, $Q$ ...) can be thought of (or can even be actually identified) who were and remained at rest with repect to $B$, and with respect to each other. Then

- either $A$ had passed some other members of the rest frame to which $B$ belongs, and eventually reached $B$ (and possibly even passed $B$). Let's say that $A$ had passed $K$, $J$, etc., but not $P$, $Q$, or others. For each passage we can evaluate the **average speed** of $A$'s motion wrt. $B$ and $K$, wrt. $B$ and $J$, and so on. Evaluating the limit of these speed values (if there is one) we obtain the **instantaneous speed** of $A$ at $B$'s indication of the passage of $A$, and we attribute a direction to $A$'s motion wrt. $B$'s rest frame (say "from $J$ to $B$").
- Or: $A$ is a member of this rest frame, too; accordingly $A$ and $B$ were at rest to each other, and the value $\vec 0$ is evaluated for $A$'s velocity with respect to $B$.

But it makes no sense to attribute a value of velocity to one photon with respect to another, because photons have no rest frame; photons cannot be said to have been at rest with respect to each other. Arguably it doesn't even make sense to talk about the movement of a photon with respect to another, at all.

See for instance: ["*Are signal fronts in a beam not at rest to each other?*" (PSE/q/104333)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/104333/are-signal-fronts-in-a-beam-not-at-rest-to-each-other).

Comment: Can't understand about the participant particles. Please can you explain it with an easier analogy.

Comment: @ASuckerinMaths: "_Can't understand about the participant particles._" -- In Einstein's writings we also find them called "observers", or  "places", named [A, B](http://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol2-trans/156?highlightText=observer), [C ...](http://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol2-trans/157?ajax), [M](http://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol6-trans/283?highlightText=observer), [M' ...](http://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol6-trans/286?ajax); or "[material points](http://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol6-trans/165?highlightText=material)".