# Would it be ok to say that not all light travels at the same speed when you consider its own perspective?

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light, photons, speed-of-light, reference-frames

The reason I am asking is because higher energy would cause greater gravitational time dilation. Therefore I would expect, from the perspective of a radio wave, a gamma ray having more energy would appear slower than its lower energy radio wave counterpart.

Comment: There is no [photon rest frame](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16018), so the question is effectively meaningless.

Comment: The fundamental postulate of special relativity is that the speed of light is a universal constant. No matter what you do, no matter what you consider, the speed of light will be $c$. So, what is the speed of the photon as seen from its own perspective? I would not say your question is meaningless. Your hypothesis is simply in contradiction with special relativity and therefore is beyond the scope of accepted physical theories.