# Do photons move from their point of view?

Tags: special-relativity, photons, reference-frames, inertial-frames, time-dilation

If at light speed time doesnt exist do photons not move from their point of view? If they dont, what would happen if you took a photon and somehow stopped it would it be at the same point at its POV that it is at your POV?

Comment: Photons do not have a point of view.  They cannot be stopped.  So the question does not have an answer in the realm of physics.   It's like asking "What would happen if my car and my truck occupied the same location in space and time?"   The situation is impossible, and there is no answer.

Comment: what do u mean photons dont have a pov everything has a pov, then lets say u somehow managed to go at light speed, would u be moving from ur pov?

Comment: What @garyp said is true but I still like to imagine that a photon spans the whole universe in its travel direction (maximum contraction) while in the perpendicular direction there is 0 contraction. This means that it "could" know where it is from the perpendicular direction. The rest of the universe is like this weird donut, the closer you get to your travel axis, the more contracted it is and you "see" it "accelerate" from the sides to the middle and then just shoot out the back. A weird concept that creates "cool?" images in my head.

Comment: Please use conventional English grammar.   Comments are not SMS messages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does a photon in vacuum have a rest frame?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16018/)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing moves in ints own rest frame, which is what I assume you mean by POV. The tricky thing with photons is that they don't have a rest frame, or rather they have it only in the sense of a limit. In the limit of a frame moving along with the photon as close as possible to $c$, the frequency and energy go to zero and the photon ceases to exist.