# Spacetime in photon frame

Tags: special-relativity, photons, spacetime, speed-of-light, inertial-frames

The time-axis and the space-axis overlap for a photon's world line. Does it mean that photon has no "past" or "future" but only "present" and no "there" but only "here"? I mean how does the photon observe the world?

Comment: It means this is not a legitimate frame.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does a photon in vacuum have a rest frame?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16018/)

Answer (score 1):

There is no photon frame as that is in direct contradiction to the fact that photon moves with the same speed in every inertial frame on which whole relativity is build.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good reason why a photon in vacuum may have no frame of reference (and by consequence, why a photon cannot make any observations):

A photon in vacuum is emitted in some point A and absorbed in some point B. The spacetime interval between the two points of emission and absorption of photons is always zero. That means that - even if A and B are separated by a spatial distance and by a time distance - their spacetime distance is zero, they are "adjacent" in spacetime, such that in spacetime there is no place neither for the path of a photon nor for any proper time.